# Web server and application server Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, passenger

Best practice for Scalable project on ruby on rails. Problem: I don't understand the difference between web and app server in ror projects.

I understood that the differences between application and web servers are webserver handles requests and application has business logic. However I don't quite understand how I can implement it in my ruby on rails application.

So, I have, for example, two instances and ruby on rails application. 
On the first server I want to set up a web server, and on the second one I want to install application server. 
But, for example, I use passengers as  my webserver that makes easier to deploy my ror application. So, will I have any benefits implementing such logic? Can I use passenger as an cache server or something like this? Is it possible to put passenger on another server and send request to ror application? Or I totally wrong and don't understand the conception?

Note: I just found amazon web application hosting architecture and now I'm trying to figure out how I can it implement and how it could work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use heroku with puma. That's the easiest to setup.

http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/a-web-server-vs-an-app-server/
https://www.nateberkopec.com/2015/07/29/scaling-ruby-apps-to-1000-rpm.html
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server

Comment: Okay. So I put puma on one server, my ror app on another and do some configuration. And where should I put my API server? Should I put it behind Load Balancer or behind Puma web server?

Comment: Also I'm interesting is there any reason to put cache server separately from Application server and the Web server with puma?

Comment: No, it's not like that. Heroku is a PaaS, not an appserver or webserver. You should read the heroku docs. You host your app on heroku and puma will deal with the ruby/rack requests/responses. As for webserver, heroku deals with that part on its own way, so basically you don't need webserver like nginx. You can add puma within your app with gem, but you have to deploy your app on heroku. Heroku gives you storage space for that, but doesn't give you space for storing your files/images/etc..

Comment: You can also check this video out for $9: https://gorails.com/episodes/deploying-to-heroku-with-puma?autoplay=1

Comment: Hm, I don't have an opportunity to use heroku and I want just to understand how it works in conceptual way. I can use amazon right now, btw.
And I tried to draw the servers infrastructure on my papers. And I don't know where I should put cache server and api server.

Comment: This is an older setup video for free with nginx+unicorn+capistrano: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSy1Bnf3WIk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109171/discussion-between-ascelhem-and-szilard-magyar).